# clang++ Name mangling

Tags: c++, llvm-clang

Anybody knows how to determine what would be the result of name mangling on a c++ function, be it in class or in a global context?

For example after compiling the following function

```
string myFunction2();
```

We will have:

> __Z11myFunction2v

as the mangled name in the object file.

Is there someway (like a tool) whiteout messing with the actual llvm internals?

Comment: I need an API and I just have the header not the body. The example requires the body to at least have something returned for clang to compile it.

Comment: @user4800 Can you explain why you need the mangled name? There might be an alternate solution to your problem.

Comment: I'm writing a lisp wrapper for C++ code. Mainly OpenCV.